# Passar variável em consulta MongoDB (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Com essa consulta:

```
const result = await Topic.find( { 'categorieName': { $regex: /^news/i } } )
```

Eu consigo retornar as categorias com nome news, o problema é que nem sempre é news, então queria colocar uma variável no lugar

Como eu faço isso?
Tenho uma variável chamada categoria que já está recebendo o valor 'news', se eu colocar no console.log, então tentei isso:

```
const result = await Topic.find(JSON.parse(`{ 'categorieName' : { $regex: /^${categoria}/i } }`));
```

Mas não funcionou, o que eu tô fazendo errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar um objeto de expressão regular com variáveis é necessário usar a classe RegExp:

```js
let reString = 'exemplo';

let re = new RegExp(`${reString}[0-9]?`, 'i');

console.log(re);

console.log('exemplo3'.match(re));

console.log('erro'.match(re));
```

A função `parse` não interpreta expressões regulares

Comment: Ahhh entendi, expressões regulares seriam tipo '\', '/' e alguma outra coisa, certo?

O que eu fiz de errado pra substituir o const result = await Topic.find( { 'categorieName': { $regex: /^news/i } } )

???

Tentei isso: https://hastebin.com/imacehigon.js
Mas me retornou esses erros: https://hastebin.com/apufayepav.makefile

Comment: você de fazer algo como: criar a expressão regular `let re = new RegExp(`${categoria}[0-9]?`, 'i');` e então passa-la na busca `Topic.find({ categorieName: { $regex: re } });`

Comment: Eu tava moscando, usando a variável errada, obrigado mano!